# Search for text within an Ionic App

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I am converting a web application to Mobile App where I have selected Ionic as the framework of my choice. In one particular section, the app loads HTML content (user entered) from backend. Since the content at times is very large client is asking for a search feature within the page. Something similar to the browser's search. 
I tried to use window.find but that doesn't work within the mobile app.

Is it possible at all to make such feature ?